# Asp.net mvc paging mechanism

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, paging

is there some elegant way, ideally with jquery plugin like [pager 1](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Pager) or [pager 2](http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/#examples) how to implement paging with asp.net mvc? I am trying to go over partial views, but so far unsucessfully. Where should I store the loaded grid data? And how to respond on the page selection with just a partial refresh?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The [MVC Contrib Grid](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Grid) comes with paging functionality. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest checking out ScottGu's [NerdDinner](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html) as he shows how to make a pager with ASP.NET MVC there.

One way you can do it is to transmit the result range via the URL, i.e.

```
http://domain.com/Products/List/0-10
```

...could show 10 products starting at 0.  If you had many search fields, another way would be to have a contoller with a List action returning JSON, XML or an HTML table that you could call using an AJAX GET.

But I highly suggest checking out NerdDinner, as he has an example of how to do this.

Comment: You will also see this explained in the Wrox MVC book (where they use NerdDinner as their sample) -- you can download and read the first chapter (which is nearly one-third of the entire book!) online for free. (Purchasing the book is more ideal, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't store the loaded data. MVC allows you to keep the view stateless, so the call back to the controller for the next page needs to include the page number being requested. Then you just return the rows required. You could also use AJAX for that.