# How to control displaying data per page

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, controls

I am working on MVC3 razor view and I need to control displaying data per page. e.g-> Client will be able to display 5 or 10.... data per page as he/she wish. There will be a drop-down list from where client will select number of data per page.

Comment: Check this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293799/asp-net-mvc-paging-mechanism)